# How to add hash to urls in react-router 4

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, url-routing

I would like to add hash to my endopints in react-router for preventing error responses from server. I'm using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer -p 8888` for creating server.

This short example works but when I'm trying reload page on some route like  `/about` then I get an error: `Error response Error code 404. Message: File not found. Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/about">About Link</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/company">Company Link</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Routes />          
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways to go around it:

1) Make your web server respond always with the same `index.html` file, no matter the route. This will prevent the 404 errors, but is not perfect as it won't support browser caching

2) Use [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) - it will keep the UI route in hash part of the URL, which should not make the server return 404 and will enable browser-side cache. The downside of this approach is that you can't use #target links to specific parts of the webpage

Comment: Thanks I've missed this part of the documentation about HashRouter.

*The downside of this approach is that you can't use #target links to specific parts of the webpage*, you're absolutely right, but if it is not a blog or something like that then I think it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks Kuba! To your second way:
I know it's not pretty but couldn't you mix the hash string with query params and use that as you #target? Lets say **.../page?linkTarget=contact-form**

Comment: I usualy end up using the query params instead of hash location, and try to have a very small and fast-loading index.html to accomodate for lack of cache

Comment: @KubaOrlik I am interested in your first solution. Is there anyone who can show how to do so using a go server (especially using packr ). But all other existing assets as images or css files should be provided as well as the `index.html`. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the documentation well, below there is the solution:

```
const Routes = () => (
    <HashRouter basename="/#">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/about">About Link</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/company">Company Link</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
);
```